Flutter dartssh2: SSHClient not authenticated
I am trying to connect to a list of servers. When authenticated I can fetch all the infomration i need. I also want to identfy servers i cannto connect to.
I am trying with this Future:
  Future<void> connectToSshClient() async {
    _sshSocket = await SSHSocket.connect(hubData.ipaddress, 22666);
    _sshClient = SSHClient(_sshSocket,
        username: 'root',
        onPasswordRequest: () => hubData.password,
        onAuthenticated: () {
          log("Authenticated");
          _fetchAllInformation();
        });
  }

I connect to a server using SSHClient from the dartssh2 package. When autenticated (onAuthenticated) i can execute some commands an log a message.
How can i log a message, e.g:
log("not authentictated");

if is not possible to authentictate.
I tried to try and catch an error, to Async/Await/then. But nothing seemed to work. I guess i is pretty obvious, but I am stuck here.
Thanks for any advice.

Switch to using the authenticated future, rather than the onAuthenticated callback.
Catch the exception (there are several types). Switch on the exception type if you are particularly interested in their differences.
Future<void> connectToSshClient() async {
  try {
    _sshClient = SSHClient(
      await SSHSocket.connect(hubData.ipaddress, 22666),
      username: 'root',
      onPasswordRequest: () => hubData.password,
    );

    await _sshClient.authenticated;

    log("Authenticated");
    _fetchAllInformation();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    log("not authenticated - or some other connection problem");
    if (e is SSHAuthFailError) {
      log("not authenticated");
    }
  }
}

